# Error in infer of rootState type | TS2339

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to infer the type of RootState but I get this error, when trying to use it in a selector:

```
const tagsSelector = (state: RootState) => state.tags;
```

```
TS2339: Property 'tags' does not exist on type 'CombinedState<{ tags: CombinedState<{ tagsSet: TagsState; }>; } | { queue: CombinedState<{ clientCard: ClientCardState; clientCardTasks: ClientCardTasksState; }>; }>'.   Property 'tags' does not exist on type '{ readonly [$CombinedState]?: undefined; } & { queue: CombinedState<{ clientCard: ClientCardState; clientCardTasks: ClientCardTasksState; }>; }'.
```

RootState type I infer that

```
const typedReducers = typedModules.map(m => m.getTypedReducers() ).reduce((accum, r) => {
    return {...accum, ...r}
});

const rootTypedReducers = combineReducers(typedReducers);

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootTypedReducers>;
```

getTypedReducers() just return root reducer of each module

```
getTypedReducers() {
        return {tags: combineReducers({
                    tagsSet: tagsReducers,
            })};
    }
```

However, if I only use one module, then everything works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how typescript has interpreted your state type:

```
CombinedState<{ tags: CombinedState<{ tagsSet: TagsState; }>; } | { queue: CombinedState<{ clientCard: ClientCardState; clientCardTasks: ClientCardTasksState; }>; }>
```

The problem is that it's an **OR** rather than an **AND**.  Your state is seen to *either* have keys `'tags'` or `'queue' | 'clientCard' | 'clientCardTasks'`.  So as far as typescript is concerned, `tags` isn't guaranteed to always be present.

This bad type is created in your `typedReducures` because you are using array functions like `map` and `reduce`.  Typescript is not able to understand that `return {...accum, ...r}` must include all of the elements of the individual `getTypedReducers()` maps.  So we need to override there return type there.

There is a classic [`UnionToIntersection` utility type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type) created by @jcalz that we can make use of here.

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
  (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never

type Reducers = UnionToIntersection<ReturnType<typeof typedModules[number]['getTypedReducers']>>

const typedReducers = typedModules.map(m => m.getTypedReducers()).reduce((accum, r) => {
  return { ...accum, ...r }
}) as Reducers;
```

Now there is no more error in the selector because all of the keys are known to definitely exist.

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/GNlo5w)